# How many coins been mined on the Testnet?

Tags: testnet

How many coins been mined on the **Testnet**? 
How can I check how many coins have been mined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By visiting http://blockexplorer.com/testnet you can browse the testnet blockchain.

As of this writing, it shows that 128558 blocks have been mined on the current iteration of testnet (testnet3).  Since each block has a reward of 50 BTC (it has not decreased), that's a total of 6427900 BTC mined to date on testnet.